# bash script error: source: not found

Tags: bash, shell-script

I must be missing a fundamental understanding about sourcing files in bash. I've tried the different approaches that seem like they should work, but I still get this error `source: not found`.

In my script I tried to cd to the directory where the file that I want to source is located before sourcing it. That didn't work.

```
cd /home/user/path/to/
source myfile
```

Neither did providing the full absolute path to the file to be sourced:

```
source /home/user/path/to/myfile
```

The error is "source: not found" with the line number of the above statement.

Is there something else, something basic, I could be overlooking? I have checked the paths I'm using and I don't see any errors. This problem is repeatable.

I'm running Ubuntu on a Linode server and my scripts all start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Is the error from 'source" or from 'myfile'?

Try: 'set -v -x; source /home/user/path/to/myfile; set +v +x

How about: alias source ; echo $SHELL ; echo $POSIXLY_CORRECT

Comment: I believe my script, when run on the server, is being called like this: `sh myscript` so even though my script starts with `#!/bin/bash` and `echo $SHELL` returns /bin/bash, source is somehow still not working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your second attempt using the absolute path should be the correct method.

Possible causes of your bug:

1. The file doesn't exist.
2. The file exists, but for some reason you can't read it (eg permissions or some filesystem error.
3. You have an `alias` which is overriding the builtin `source` (fix with `unalias source`)
4. You have a function which is overriding `source` (fix with `unset -f source`)
5. You are somehow not using `bash` (although your bang line would suggest you are). `source` is not POSIX. Using `source` on `dash` does not work, only `.` works.
6. My test with `source` with `bash` in POSIX mode worked, though maybe this is due to my version or compilation flags. Maybe this is different for you and you are in POSIX mode.

1 and 5 give errors like the one you posted.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I believe my script, when run on the server, is being called like this: `sh myscript` so even though my script starts with `#!/bin/bash` that is somehow not enough. So... how do I source a file in this case? Thanks

Comment: I checked further. It is somehow using `dash` (seemingly b/c it is called with `sh myscript` on Ubuntu). Using the `dash` dot notation (`.`) to source works. But is there a way to force my script to run in bash? Bash is available.

Comment: @MountainX, the bang line isn't read by the interpreter, it is read by the kernel when you try to execute the file.

Comment: You have to use `bash` to run the script or set executable permissions and execute directly.

Comment: @MountainX You could symlink `sh` to `bash`, but this would likely mess up your system in other ways. Plus you would then be running in POSIX mode and not have all the `bash` features.

Comment: @MountainX, if you can't control how the script is invoked, you can always just have two scripts - one which runs the other. Though if you script integrates with your system (eg an init script) I recommend sticking with `dash` and writing POSIX compliant code.

Comment: I just used `.` instead of `source` in my script and that resolved it. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: I was too lazy to call chmod script.sh so I called it using sh script.sh. Calling it using bash script.sh did work. Also, because it had a shebang line, calling it ./script.sh after chmod'ing it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably logging in with a user that runs a shell other than bash. Suppose you log in with user X and X runs `sh` or another shell, not bash, and with user X you run `source myscript.sh`, then you should get the given error.

Comment: Thank you. I believe my script, when run on the server, is being called like this: `sh myscript` so even though my script starts with `#!/bin/bash` that is somehow not enough. So... how do I source a file in this case? Thanks

Comment: step 1: `chmod +x myscript.sh`  step 2: `path/myscript.sh`

Comment: @MountainX If you have no control over what is running your script, you can use the standard name `.` instead of the bash synonym `source`.

Comment: @Gilles - that worked. I used `.`. I didn't know it was the "standard" name and that `source` was just a synonym for it.

Comment: source actually came from the cshell, and the bourne shell originally used `.`

Answer (score 6):

I was stack with similar problem when running stuff from rpm.spec file.

I fixed the problem by providing explicit path to the script.

So, instead of

```
source myfile
```

I had to to run

```
source ./myfile
```

I am not sure what was the exact reason for that but it looks like myfile was searched for on $PATH and in $CWD. I guess that is up to some configuration in shell.

Comment: This is the documented behavior of source. Type `help source` at the Bash prompt to see why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Be sure that the script is actually being interpreted by `bash`.
2. If the name you use with `source` does not contain a slash, `bash` will look for it in `$PATH`.

The script will *not* be interpreted by `bash` if you explicitly run it with e.g. `sh script`.  It *will* be interpreted by `bash` if it's executable and its first line is `#!/bin/bash` (adjust the path to match the location of the `bash` binary on your system) and you run it with `./script`, or if you run it with `bash script`.

Also, according to the `bash` manual, `source filename` will

> Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell
>                 environment and return the exit status of the last command
>                 executed from `filename`.  **If `filename` does not contain a slash,
>                 filenames in `PATH` are used to find the directory containing
>                 `filename`.**